# How to read file content from an http.Request's response

Tags: go, multipart, content-disposition

I use below code to send a request to an http server.

The server sends a response that contains those http headers

```
Content-Disposition:[attachment;filename=somefilename.csv] 
Content-Type:[text/csv; charset=UTF-8]
```

How do i proceed to retrieve the content of the file attached with the response ?

```
baseUrl := "Some url that i call to fetch csv file"

client := http.Client{}

resp, _ := client.Get(baseUrl)
defer resp.Body.Close()

fmt.Println(resp)

// &{200 OK 200 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map[Content-Disposition:[attachment;filename=somefilename.csv] Content-Type:[text/csv; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Mon, 30 Sep 2019 09:54:08 GMT] Server:[Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)] Vary:[Accept]] {0xc000530280} -1 [] false false map[] 0xc000156200 0xc0000c26e0}
```

Comment: The file is not part of this HTTP Header.

Comment: he does not have a clue what he is doing. Unless it can be marked as duplicate, please help to improve the question / response instead of throwing close votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to consume the body of the request.

```
baseUrl := "Some url that i call to fetch csv file"

client := http.Client{}

resp, _ := client.Get(baseUrl)
defer resp.Body.Close()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body) // this line.

fmt.Println(resp)
```

if you have to deal with a multipart form data https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile

Given following comment,

> i see now after printing resp that there is a csv text but type is
>   http.Response i have to deal with golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader
>   how to turn resp to string in order to be able reader to read it, or i
>   miss something else ?

OP has to understand that an http response Body implements the `io.Reader` interface.
When the http response come back from the server, the body is not read directly into memory as slice of bytes `[]byte`.

OP should note also that a `csv.Reader` is an implementation to decode a CSV encoded content that consumes an `io.Reader`. Under the hood it does not hold the entire content of the file in memory, it reads whats needed to decode one line and proceed further.

As a consequence to those two important properties of golang implementation, is that it is easy and natural to connect the response body reader to the csv reader.

To the question, what is an `io.Reader`, OP has to figure out it is anything capable of reading a byte stream by chunks of max len p. This is illustrated by the signature of the unique method of this interface `Read([]byte) (int, error)`

This interface is designed in such way that it minimizes consumed memory and allocations.

ref links

- https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader
- https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader
- https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response

All that being said, the final code is trivially written,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    baseUrl := "https://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/misc/region_codes.csv"

    client := http.Client{}

    resp, err := client.Get(baseUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(resp)

    r := csv.NewReader(resp.Body)

    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}
```

Comment: i see now after printing resp that there is a csv text but type is http.Response

i have to deal with https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader 

how to turn resp to string in order to be able reader to read it, or i miss something else ?

Comment: see my answer for that

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `ioutil.ReadAll` method to read the entire body. The body implements the `io.Reader` interface, so everything you can do with a reader can be done with the body. That includes piping it to stdout as mh-cbon has shown in his answer.

```golang
baseUrl := "Some url that i call to fetch csv file"

resp, err := http.Get(baseUrl)
if err != nil {
    // do something with the error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    // do something with the error
}

fmt.Println(string(content))
```

Note that I removed the `client`. It is not needed for simple `GET` calls. If you need more configuration use the `http.Client` as you did in your example.

Also note that `content` is of type `[]byte` but it can easily be converted to string as done above in the print statement.

Comment: i was unhappy you proposed a string conversion so i updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, very nice! I tried to give the simplest answer but also point out that the body is a `io.Reader`. Reading the body at once is a bad idea with large files and streaming it is way superior... but a lot more complex -- especially for beginners.